# How to get $ to select css in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm on version 58 of Google Chrome on MacOS.  When I try to do a `$('#userName')` type selector, I get the following:

```
$('#userName')
VM193870:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM193870:1
```

However, according to this page, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions#select_elements, I should be able to do that without any problems.

`$$('#userName')` does work and returns the list of a single element.

```
$$('#userName')
[input#userName.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.mat-input-element]
```

Is there something I need to enable?

Comment: What does a `console.log($)` show ...?

Comment: `undefined`  ... hmm.  I wonder if the app I'm testing causes that.  You know, I think that's the case. It works fine when I test on this page.

Comment: I was asking rather expecting it to be a scalar value of some sorts ... Don't know why particularly an app might feel the need to "unset" it; but it is probably something like that, especially since you can confirm it works on other sites.

Comment: Whenever the page (or selected page context) overrides/provides its own `$` the console will use it, and AFAIK there's no way to invoke the original `$` from the browser's console API.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation revealed that the angular 2 app I'm working on somehow clobbers the $ operator.  If you are experiencing this issue, first check to see if it will work on another website (use a different tab). It may also be an extension that clobbers it.